# sqldf python OperationalError

Tags: python, pandas, sqldf

I am trying to run a query:

```
from pandasql import sqldf

dfinal.shape
# (137, 15)

sqldf("select * from dfinal where area < 150000 and h1>10 and StdAvg>15 and w1<1000")
```

dfinal has 137 rows and 15 columns, And I got this error:

```
OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) too many SQL variables [SQL: 'INSERT INTO dfinal (p1, p2, p3, p4, h1, w1, t, x1m, y1m, area, len, "RStd", "GStd", "BStd", "StdAvg") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: (0.0, 1279.0, 0.0, 719.0, 719.0, 1279.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 919601.0, 4.0, 39.57491151123238, 39.721341845203305, 41.66312140715773, 40.31979158786447, 0.0, 1279.0, 0.0, 719.0, 719.0, 1279.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 919601.0, 4.0, 39.57491151123238, 39.721341845203305, 41.66312140715773, 40.31979158786447, 0.0, 1265.0, 0.0, 719.0, 719.0, 1265.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 909535.0, 2.0, 39.70990014713196, 39.864980423613375, 41.79363195910364, 40.45617084328299, 483.0, 764.0, 528.0, 599.0, 71.0, 281.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 19951.0, 2.0, 50.08926583415047, 50.08223957695191, 50.08366140564431, 50.08505560558223, 3.0, 1279.0, 0.0, 579.0, 579.0, 1276.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 738804.0, 2.0, 40.905123366023155, 41.131524355676795, 42.63973130010851, 41.558793007269486, 306.0, 1279.0, 420.0, 569.0, 149.0, 973.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 144977.0, 2.0, 46.209193569658304, 46.12013625686914, 46.10518656748261, 46.14483879800335, 435.0, 754.0, 147.0, 177.0, 30.0, 319.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9570.0, 2.0, 39.193632313456, 39.20143253664268, 39.16507303720572, 39.186712629101464, 985.0, 1211.0, 372.0, 415.0, 43.0, 226.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9718.0, 2.0, 48.44113921617965, 48.30613947293776, 48.31045393610698, 48.35257754174146, 0.0, 1279.0, 1.0, 143.0, 142.0, 1279.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 181618.0, 2.0, 24.3776417456023, 24.379749948672533, 26.553068777138066, 25.1034868238043, 306.0, 1210.0, 148.0, 273.0, 125.0, 904.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 113000.0, 2.0, 45.552289644078236, 47.93742656107743, 44.47074498663213, 45.9868203972626, 307.0, 1210.0, 419.0, 464.0, 45.0, 903.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 40635.0, 2.0, 42.4475079484597, 42.21198175238492, 42.21421664215395, 42.291235447666196, 67.0, 293.0, 323.0, 465.0, 142.0, 226.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 32092.0, 4.0, 34.830002324557704, 34.75653975786014, 34.75914729837388, 34.78189646026391, 67.0, 293.0, 179.0, 306.0, 127.0, 226.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 28702.0, 2.0, 31.695270129961408, 31.681681023012715, 31.6822107359683, 31.68638729631414, 533.0, 1210.0, 275.0, 320.0, 45.0, 677.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 30465.0, 2.0, 32.70759143390099, 32.76662114065409, 32.76811066430549, 32.74744107962019, 533.0, 983.0, 323.0, 368.0, 45.0, 450.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 20250.0, 2.0, 24.549111559161464, 24.59639355449945, 24.598193720871514, 24.581232944844146, 533.0, 983.0, 371.0, 416.0, 45.0, 450.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 20250.0, 2.0, 29.646486396275805, 29.747412217750924, 29.748332124633993, 29.714076912886906, 90.0, 266.0, 486.0, 621.0, 135.0, 176.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 23760.0, 2.0, 64.5669285720487, 61.134200540423876, 64.70707617429815, 63.469401762256915, 305.0, 530.0, 372.0, 416.0, 44.0, 225.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9900.0, 2.0, 42.55565721899592, 42.55807393342376, 42.55909530421138, 42.55760881887702, 985.0, 1210.0, 324.0, 368.0, 44.0, 225.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9900.0, 2.0, 36.09693478944931, 36.137220059732684, 36.13877455848668, 36.12430980255622, 2.0, 1279.0, 2.0, 143.0, 141.0, 1277.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 180057.0, 2.0, 24.456162687817823, 24.45849152471971, 26.641949987730175, 25.18553473342257, 306.0, 1210.0, 228.0, 273.0, 45.0, 904.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 40680.0, 2.0, 25.38404536515433, 25.177404357534975, 25.1869351289109, 25.24946161720007, 306.0, 1096.0, 150.0, 223.0, 73.0, 790.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 57670.0, 2.0, 46.73828157240198, 48.443794209476046, 53.529878442649945, 49.57065140817599, 533.0, 1210.0, 276.0, 320.0, 44.0, 677.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 29788.0, 2.0, 32.80087017499071, 32.86318955496181, 32.864853195657325, 32.842970975203286, 307.0, 960.0, 419.0, 465.0, 46.0, 653.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 30038.0, 2.0, 37.4876834994048, 37.4261475581113, 37.425412333739395, 37.446414463751836, 533.0, 983.0, 372.0, 416.0, 44.0, 450.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 19800.0, 2.0, 29.697672707957302, 29.811943490078722, 29.81301212405397, 29.774209440696666, 533.0, 983.0, 324.0, 368.0, 44.0, 450.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 19800.0, 2.0, 24.525238962937024, 24.57980073273195, 24.581978449327792, 24.56233938166559, 90.0, 266.0, 486.0, 621.0, 135.0, 176.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 23760.0, 3.0, 64.5669285720487, 61.134200540423876, 64.70707617429815, 63.469401762256915, 963.0, 1210.0, 420.0, 463.0, 43.0, 247.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10621.0, 2.0, 50.236729155918226, 49.91316318037975, 49.91720327174873, 50.02236520268224, 64.0, 293.0, 249.0, 272.0, 23.0, 229.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5267.0, 2.0, 28.344278373319852, 28.344278373319852, 28.344278373319852, 28.344278373319852, 64.0, 293.0, 297.0, 320.0, 23.0, 229.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5267.0, 2.0, 34.042747279691675, 34.041307623200375, 34.041307623200375, 34.041787508697475, 64.0, 293.0, 345.0, 368.0, 23.0, 229.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5267.0, 2.0, 34.564783861030065, 34.56055967161997, 34.56055967161997, 34.56196773475667, 64.0, 293.0, 201.0, 224.0, 23.0, 229.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5267.0, 2.0, 29.14696287880518, 29.14696287880518, 29.14696287880518, 29.14696287880518, 64.0, 293.0, 372.0, 393.0, 21.0, 229.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4809.0, 2.0, 32.74547710936744, 32.74143620258873, 32.74143620258873, 32.742783171514965, 306.0, 530.0, 276.0, 320.0, 44.0, 224.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9856.0, 2.0, 44.84714560883013, 44.72831309175789, 44.72831309175789, 44.76792393078197, 64.0, 292.0, 441.0, 464.0, 23.0, 228.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5244.0, 2.0, 36.43605084818249, 36.29494261028493, 36.30726861764889, 36.34608735870544, 306.0, 530.0, 372.0, 416.0, 44.0, 224.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9856.0, 2.0, 42.366581243047705, 42.36746996497164, 42.368525656062246, 42.36752562136053, 306.0, 530.0, 324.0, 368.0, 44.0, 224.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9856.0, 2.0, 38.84693067655511, 38.894681233530335, 38.89976885830451, 38.880460256129986, 986.0, 1210.0, 324.0, 368.0, 44.0, 224.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9856.0, 2.0, 36.11284465179385, 36.1539882434708, 36.155574675718974, 36.140802523661215, 30.0, 1279.0, 56.0, 143.0, 87.0, 1249.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 108663.0, 2.0, 25.93711849247151, 25.936520382517063, 28.42225733551669, 26.76529873683509, 307.0, 1210.0, 227.0, 272.0, 45.0, 903.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 40635.0, 2.0, 25.955267027172592, 25.788275467688905, 25.79480865676373, 25.846117050541746, 533.0, 1210.0, 276.0, 319.0, 43.0, 677.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 29111.0, 2.0, 33.15890292128785, 33.2223585301032, 33.22408324989097, 33.20178156709401, 307.0, 960.0, 420.0, 464.0, 44.0, 653.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 28732.0, 2.0, 37.164747141789405, 37.11489317324743, 37.115248039993595, 37.13162945167681, 533.0, 983.0, 372.0, 416.0, 44.0, 450.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 19800.0, 2.0, 29.697672707957302, 29.811943490078722, 29.81301212405397, 29.774209440696666, 533.0, 983.0, 324.0, 368.0, 44.0, 450.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 19800.0, 2.0, 24.525238962937024, 24.57980073273195, 24.581978449327792, 24.56233938166559, 90.0, 266.0, 486.0, 621.0, 135.0, 176.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 23760.0, 3.0, 64.5669285720487, 61.134200540423876, 64.70707617429815, 63.469401762256915, 763.0, 1096.0, 181.0, 183.0, 2.0, 333.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 666.0, 2.0, 1.0647890249056153, 0.7358904660486263, 0.8333319806281801, 0.8780038238608072, 963.0, 1210.0, 420.0, 463.0, 43.0, 247.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10621.0, 2.0, 50.236729155918226, 49.91316318037975, 49.91720327174873, 50.02236520268224, 64.0, 293.0, 374.0, 394.0, 20.0, 229.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4580.0, 2.0, 34.594182786231066, 34.59782645350871, 34.59782645350871, 34.59661189774949, 65.0, 292.0, 343.0, 368.0, 25.0, 227.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5675.0, 2.0, 35.66953761451219, 35.66953761451219, 35.66953761451219, 35.66953761451219, 307.0, 530.0, 275.0, 320.0, 45.0, 223.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10035.0, 2.0, 45.08863341720841, 44.96551404181749, 44.96551404181749, 45.00655383361447, 64.0, 293.0, 231.0, 250.0, 19.0, 229.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4351.0, 2.0, 29.468435449812958, 29.47241489065707, 29.47241489065707, 29.4710884103757, 65.0, 293.0, 279.0, 295.0, 16.0, 228.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 3648.0, 2.0, 30.125067127536052, 30.125067127536052, 30.125067127536052, 30.125067127536052, 65.0, 292.0, 199.0, 224.0, 25.0, 227.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5675.0, 2.0, 29.602476861060982, 29.602476861060982, 29.602476861060982, 29.602476861060982, 65.0, 292.0, 439.0, 464.0, 25.0, 227.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5675.0, 2.0, 37.799222009574486, 37.67240413374553, 37.68126184452296, 37.71762932928099, 307.0, 530.0, 323.0, 368.0, 45.0, 223.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10035.0, 2.0, 39.1218405095613, 39.15231547100605, 39.156826897640364, 39.143660959402574, 307.0, 530.0, 371.0, 416.0, 45.0, 223.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10035.0, 2.0, 42.66352245588468, 42.62099613395702, 42.62195291769499, 42.635490502512226, 986.0, 1210.0, 324.0, 367.0, 43.0, 224.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9632.0, 2.0, 36.50371958572536, 36.5416890804253, 36.54323019982375, 36.52954628865813, 307.0, 479.0, 148.0, 223.0, 75.0, 172.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12900.0, 3.0, 60.159869337933955, 62.07128926499407, 62.670169989174006, 61.63377619736735, 59.0, 1103.0, 2.0, 63.0, 61.0, 1044.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 63684.0, 2.0, 20.410637295852812, 20.56947067236059, 20.568222986027386, 20.516110318080262, 307.0, 1210.0, 228.0, 272.0, 44.0, 903.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 39732.0, 2.0, 25.36105184187513, 25.161879283211917, 25.170940818143812, 25.23129064774362, 726.0, 1279.0, 1.0, 112.0, 111.0, 553.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 61383.0, 2.0, 30.977684857365663, 30.946844402894698, 35.416612510102446, 32.447047256787606, 533.0, 1210.0, 277.0, 319.0, 42.0, 677.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 28434.0, 2.0, 33.479263864990244, 33.54480084215576, 33.54662751711685, 33.52356407475429, 307.0, 960.0, 420.0, 464.0, 44.0, 653.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 28732.0, 2.0, 37.164747141789405, 37.11489317324743, 37.115248039993595, 37.13162945167681, 533.0, 983.0, 324.0, 367.0, 43.0, 450.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 19350.0, 2.0, 24.798384244613484, 24.85431751325854, 24.856581916925066, 24.83642789159903, 533.0, 983.0, 372.0, 415.0, 43.0, 450.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 19350.0, 2.0, 30.02560329931281, 30.1405808510545, 30.14166244573152, 30.102615532032946, 90.0, 266.0, 486.0, 620.0, 134.0, 176.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 23584.0, 3.0, 64.60766013112793, 61.123406055994685, 64.6624638086226, 63.46450999858174, 963.0, 1210.0, 420.0, 463.0, 43.0, 247.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10621.0, 2.0, 50.236729155918226, 49.91316318037975, 49.91720327174873, 50.02236520268224, 65.0, 292.0, 248.0, 272.0, 24.0, 227.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5448.0, 2.0, 28.832736360804393, 28.832736360804393, 28.832736360804393, 28.832736360804393, 65.0, 292.0, 296.0, 320.0, 24.0, 227.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5448.0, 2.0, 34.60795004866038, 34.60795004866038, 34.60795004866038, 34.60795004866038, 65.0, 292.0, 200.0, 224.0, 24.0, 227.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5448.0, 2.0, 29.33390955833913, 29.33390955833913, 29.33390955833913, 29.33390955833913, 65.0, 292.0, 344.0, 368.0, 24.0, 227.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5448.0, 2.0, 35.172230110950736, 35.172230110950736, 35.172230110950736, 35.172230110950736, 65.0, 292.0, 392.0, 416.0, 24.0, 227.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5448.0, 2.0, 33.987649078212876, 33.98546543802828, 33.98546543802828, 33.98619331808981, 307.0, 530.0, 276.0, 320.0, 44.0, 223.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9812.0, 2.0, 44.735863783740136, 44.610254991773715, 44.610254991773715, 44.652124589095855, 307.0, 530.0, 323.0, 368.0, 45.0, 223.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10035.0, 2.0, 39.1218405095613, 39.15231547100605, 39.156826897640364, 39.143660959402574, 307.0, 530.0, 372.0, 416.0, 44.0, 223.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9812.0, 2.0, 42.23941035248715, 42.23893507379414, 42.240021148148244, 42.23945552480985, 65.0, 292.0, 440.0, 464.0, 24.0, 227.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5448.0, 2.0, 37.07108508482556, 36.94392131248073, 36.953184844151004, 36.989397080485766, 986.0, 1210.0, 324.0, 367.0, 43.0, 224.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9632.0, 2.0, 36.50371958572536, 36.5416890804253, 36.54323019982375, 36.52954628865813, 307.0, 1210.0, 228.0, 272.0, 44.0, 903.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 39732.0, 2.0, 25.36105184187513, 25.161879283211917, 25.170940818143812, 25.23129064774362, 307.0, 960.0, 420.0, 464.0, 44.0, 653.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 28732.0, 2.0, 37.164747141789405, 37.11489317324743, 37.115248039993595, 37.13162945167681, 533.0, 1209.0, 278.0, 319.0, 41.0, 676.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 27716.0, 2.0, 33.87579649981831, 33.94334939671751, 33.94525791449064, 33.92146793700882, 88.0, 306.0, 0.0, 129.0, 129.0, 218.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 28122.0, 4.0, 30.913844911516936, 30.817563728929183, 30.796582195386065, 30.84266361194406, 533.0, 982.0, 325.0, 367.0, 42.0, 449.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 18858.0, 2.0, 25.061132058493897, 25.12111310865903, 25.12357000741987, 25.101938391524268, 533.0, 982.0, 373.0, 407.0, 34.0, 449.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 15266.0, 2.0, 33.546878309682484, 33.67683034859487, 33.67798324558002, 33.63389730128579, 90.0, 266.0, 487.0, 620.0, 133.0, 176.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 23408.0, 2.0, 64.75047630868416, 61.22018986636029, 64.66902647454324, 63.54656421652923, 963.0, 1209.0, 421.0, 463.0, 42.0, 246.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10332.0, 2.0, 50.75117702263235, 50.42851202987782, 50.43283642507333, 50.53750849252784, 307.0, 530.0, 324.0, 368.0, 44.0, 223.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9812.0, 2.0, 38.705569618391266, 38.75483942352106, 38.76010995814006, 38.740173000017464, 307.0, 530.0, 276.0, 320.0, 44.0, 223.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9812.0, 2.0, 44.735863783740136, 44.610254991773715, 44.610254991773715, 44.652124589095855, 307.0, 530.0, 372.0, 415.0, 43.0, 223.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9589.0, 2.0, 42.65399256439125, 42.65248214034352, 42.653612490710245, 42.65336239848167, 65.0, 292.0, 392.0, 416.0, 24.0, 227.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5448.0, 2.0, 33.987649078212876, 33.98546543802828, 33.98546543802828, 33.98619331808981, 65.0, 292.0, 248.0, 272.0, 24.0, 227.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5448.0, 2.0, 28.832736360804393, 28.832736360804393, 28.832736360804393, 28.832736360804393, 65.0, 292.0, 344.0, 368.0, 24.0, 227.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5448.0, 2.0, 35.172230110950736, 35.172230110950736, 35.172230110950736, 35.172230110950736, 65.0, 292.0, 296.0, 320.0, 24.0, 227.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5448.0, 2.0, 34.60795004866038, 34.60795004866038, 34.60795004866038, 34.60795004866038, 65.0, 292.0, 200.0, 224.0, 24.0, 227.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5448.0, 2.0, 29.33390955833913, 29.33390955833913, 29.33390955833913, 29.33390955833913, 65.0, 292.0, 440.0, 464.0, 24.0, 227.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5448.0, 2.0, 37.07108508482556, 36.94392131248073, 36.953184844151004, 36.989397080485766, 986.0, 1209.0, 325.0, 367.0, 42.0, 223.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9366.0, 2.0, 36.934741305498356, 36.975144204405794, 36.97678065090497, 36.962222053603035, 307.0, 1210.0, 228.0, 271.0, 43.0, 903.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 38829.0, 2.0, 25.639177118174672, 25.439345520396483, 25.448701600462744, 25.509074746344634, 307.0, 960.0, 420.0, 463.0, 43.0, 653.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 28079.0, 2.0, 37.55189180791537, 37.501453211884495, 37.50184526690231, 37.518396762234055, 96.0, 306.0, 0.0, 111.0, 111.0, 210.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 23310.0, 4.0, 32.083699864139554, 31.979916911647187, 31.94349636074399, 32.002371045510245, 307.0, 530.0, 324.0, 367.0, 43.0, 223.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9589.0, 2.0, 39.09423630171221, 39.14420130059797, 39.14957034055003, 39.1293359809534, 307.0, 530.0, 276.0, 319.0, 43.0, 223.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9589.0, 2.0, 45.156648636745814, 45.03103027475817, 45.03103027475817, 45.072903062087384, 307.0, 530.0, 372.0, 415.0, 43.0, 223.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9589.0, 2.0, 42.65399256439125, 42.65248214034352, 42.653612490710245, 42.65336239848167, 65.0, 292.0, 392.0, 416.0, 24.0, 227.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5448.0, 2.0, 33.987649078212876, 33.98546543802828, 33.98546543802828, 33.98619331808981, 65.0, 292.0, 296.0, 320.0, 24.0, 227.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5448.0, 2.0, 34.60795004866038, 34.60795004866038, 34.60795004866038, 34.60795004866038, 65.0, 292.0, 248.0, 272.0, 24.0, 227.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5448.0, 2.0, 28.832736360804393, 28.832736360804393, 28.832736360804393, 28.832736360804393, 65.0, 292.0, 344.0, 368.0, 24.0, 227.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5448.0, 2.0, 35.172230110950736, 35.172230110950736, 35.172230110950736, 35.172230110950736, 65.0, 292.0, 200.0, 224.0, 24.0, 227.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5448.0, 2.0, 29.33390955833913, 29.33390955833913, 29.33390955833913, 29.33390955833913, 65.0, 292.0, 441.0, 463.0, 22.0, 227.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4994.0, 2.0, 36.864978292961986, 36.746567750099366, 36.75561325088898, 36.78905309798344, 114.0, 266.0, 487.0, 620.0, 133.0, 152.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 20216.0, 3.0, 63.8346405159518, 60.81542774152405, 64.16169264829462, 62.93725363525683, 90.0, 160.0, 487.0, 620.0, 133.0, 70.0, 9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9310.0, 3.0, 70.67551384951841, 67.1562932454084, 72.420782507626, 70.08419653418427, 307.0, 1210.0, 228.0, 271.0, 43.0, 903.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 38829.0, 2.0, 25.639177118174672, 25.439345520396483, 25.448701600462744, 25.509074746344634, 307.0, 960.0, 420.0, 463.0, 43.0, 653.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 28079.0, 2.0, 37.55189180791537, 37.501453211884495, 37.50184526690231, 37.518396762234055, 106.0, 306.0, 0.0, 80.0, 80.0, 200.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 16000.0, 3.0, 35.71056670120335, 35.688131202769554, 35.700910606328996, 35.699869503433966, 307.0, 530.0, 324.0, 367.0, 43.0, 223.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9589.0, 2.0, 39.09423630171221, 39.14420130059797, 39.14957034055003, 39.1293359809534, 307.0, 530.0, 276.0, 319.0, 43.0, 223.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9589.0, 2.0, 45.156648636745814, 45.03103027475817, 45.03103027475817, 45.072903062087384, 307.0, 530.0, 372.0, 415.0, 43.0, 223.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9589.0, 2.0, 42.65399256439125, 42.65248214034352, 42.653612490710245, 42.65336239848167, 65.0, 292.0, 393.0, 415.0, 22.0, 227.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4994.0, 2.0, 33.90388714336899, 33.90340277690443, 33.90340277690443, 33.90356423239262, 65.0, 292.0, 249.0, 271.0, 22.0, 227.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4994.0, 2.0, 28.659000394317427, 28.659000394317427, 28.659000394317427, 28.659000394317427, 65.0, 292.0, 345.0, 367.0, 22.0, 227.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4994.0, 2.0, 35.053474417389985, 35.053474417389985, 35.053474417389985, 35.053474417389985, 65.0, 292.0, 297.0, 319.0, 22.0, 227.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4994.0, 2.0, 34.507268353839976, 34.507268353839976, 34.507268353839976, 34.507268353839976, 65.0, 292.0, 201.0, 223.0, 22.0, 227.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4994.0, 2.0, 29.461763122623946, 29.461763122623946, 29.461763122623946, 29.461763122623946, 65.0, 292.0, 420.0, 442.0, 22.0, 227.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4994.0, 2.0, 35.817814271774296, 35.713218598909975, 35.713218598909975, 35.74808382319808, 114.0, 266.0, 487.0, 620.0, 133.0, 152.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 20216.0, 4.0, 63.8346405159518, 60.81542774152405, 64.16169264829462, 62.93725363525683, 90.0, 157.0, 487.0, 620.0, 133.0, 67.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8911.0, 3.0, 70.20829437224343, 66.78962006916859, 72.1181862971903, 69.70536691286745, 307.0, 1210.0, 228.0, 271.0, 43.0, 903.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 38829.0, 2.0, 25.639177118174672, 25.439345520396483, 25.448701600462744, 25.509074746344634, 307.0, 960.0, 420.0, 463.0, 43.0, 653.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 28079.0, 2.0, 37.55189180791537, 37.501453211884495, 37.50184526690231, 37.518396762234055, 113.0, 306.0, 1.0, 59.0, 58.0, 193.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 11194.0, 2.0, 28.33263699356364, 28.182539725034072, 28.183201075787935, 28.23279259812855, 307.0, 530.0, 276.0, 319.0, 43.0, 223.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9589.0, 2.0, 45.156648636745814, 45.03103027475817, 45.03103027475817, 45.072903062087384, 65.0, 292.0, 228.0, 250.0, 22.0, 227.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4994.0, 2.0, 27.909166995067284, 27.912584759733157, 27.912584759733157, 27.911445504844533, 65.0, 292.0, 324.0, 346.0, 22.0, 227.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4994.0, 2.0, 34.25185097181471, 34.249692392339384, 34.249692392339384, 34.250411918831155, 65.0, 292.0, 276.0, 298.0, 22.0, 227.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4994.0, 2.0, 31.973888936793344, 31.973888936793344, 31.973888936793344, 31.973888936793344, 66.0, 292.0, 200.0, 223.0, 23.0, 226.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5198.0, 2.0, 29.62310660912378, 29.62310660912378, 29.62310660912378, 29.62310660912378, 65.0, 292.0, 372.0, 394.0, 22.0, 227.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4994.0, 2.0, 33.37918251870365, 33.379823610559626, 33.379823610559626, 33.3796099132743, 307.0, 530.0, 324.0, 367.0, 43.0, 223.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9589.0, 2.0, 39.09423630171221, 39.14420130059797, 39.14957034055003, 39.1293359809534, 66.0, 292.0, 440.0, 463.0, 23.0, 226.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5198.0, 2.0, 37.524795532883374, 37.41939246950593, 37.42571360052223, 37.45663386763717, 307.0, 530.0, 372.0, 415.0, 43.0, 223.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9589.0, 2.0, 42.65399256439125, 42.65248214034352, 42.653612490710245, 42.65336239848167, 114.0, 266.0, 487.0, 618.0, 131.0, 152.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 19912.0, 4.0, 63.983969151909086, 60.84292637991141, 64.15985453481822, 62.99558335554624, 91.0, 157.0, 487.0, 597.0, 110.0, 66.0, 11.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7260.0, 3.0, 65.84711753052599, 62.66636640584515, 67.15511250183572, 65.22286547940229)] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

Answer (score 0):

not an answer to the question but I got the same error and I have ~10columns. I reduced the DF to 7 columns (because i could live with dropping other columns) and it worked.

Might not be a good idea if you'd have more than 20-30 columns but you could have partial DFs of 7 columns, do your SQL stuff and then join them at a later stage.

Not efficient but a workaround.